# You tube search list api needs refresh to get the response

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Below is my JSP page

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="search.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onClientLoad" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="buttons">
            <label> <input id="query" type="text"/><button id="search-button"  onclick="search1()">Search</button></label>
        </div>
        <pre id="response"></pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my search.js

```
function showResponse(response) {
    var responseString = JSON.stringify(response, '', 2);
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML += responseString;
}

// Called automatically when JavaScript client library is loaded.
function onClientLoad() {
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', onYouTubeApiLoad);
}

// Called automatically when YouTube API interface is loaded (see line 9).
function onYouTubeApiLoad() {

    gapi.client.setApiKey('myapi');

    //search1();
}

function search1() {
    // Use the JavaScript client library to create a search.list() API call.
    //onClientLoad();

    var q = $("#query").val();

    var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
        q: q,
        part: 'snippet'

    });

    // Send the request to the API server,
    // and invoke onSearchRepsonse() with the response.
    request.execute(onSearchResponse);
}

// Called automatically with the response of the YouTube API request.
function onSearchResponse(response) {
    showResponse(response);
}
```

I am able to get response when landing on the page for the first time , but when I enter into search input a new query and try to search it doesn't give any output unless I refresh the page again. This has to do with the onClientLoad() mehtod.How can I overcome this ?